# wordpress custom post type twenty seventeen child theme

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming, child-theming

Friends i created a child theme using twentyseventeen theme and I am trying to have a custom post to display multiple products along with there categories. I used the following codes and it works fine in displaying all products just the way i want to, BUT when clicked on any product to open product details then it gives an error of 404 not found.
Kindly help me to solve this issue, thanks in advance.

here is the code from **function.php** file

```
add_action( 'init', 'rmcc_create_post_type' );
function rmcc_create_post_type() {  // clothes custom post type
// set up labels
$labels = array(
    'name' => 'Products',
    'singular_name' => 'Product',
    'add_new' => 'Add New',
    'add_new_item' => 'Add New Product',
    'edit_item' => 'Edit Product',
    'new_item' => 'New Product',
    'all_items' => 'All Products',
    'view_item' => 'View Product',
    'search_items' => 'Search Product',
    'not_found' =>  'No Product Found',
    'not_found_in_trash' => 'No Product found in Trash',
    'parent_item_colon' => '',
    'menu_name' => 'Products',
);
register_post_type(
    'Products',
    array(
        'labels' => $labels,
        'has_archive' => true,
        'public' => true,
        'hierarchical' => true,
        'supports' => array( 'title', 'editor', 'excerpt', 'custom-fields', 'thumbnail','page-attributes' ),
        'taxonomies' => array( 'post_tag', 'category' ),
        'exclude_from_search' => true,
        'capability_type' => 'post',
    )
);
}

// SHORTCODE

add_shortcode( 'list-posts-basic', 'rmcc_post_listing_shortcode' );
function rmcc_post_listing_shortcode( $atts ) {
ob_start();


// define attributes and their defaults
extract( shortcode_atts( array (
    'category' => '',
), $atts ) );

// define query parameters based on attributes
$options = array(
    'post_type' => 'Products',
    'category_name' => $category,
    'posts_per_page' => -1,
    'order' => 'ASC',
    'orderby' => 'title',
);

$query = new WP_Query( $options );
if ( $query->have_posts() ) { ?>


<div class="gallery">
    <div class="gallery-sortbar" id="portfolio-filter">
    <a href="#all" title="">All</a>
    <?php
    /**Code for get terms*/
    // no default values. using these as examples

    $taxonomy = 'category';
    $category_id = get_term_by('name',$category, $taxonomy);
    $term_id = $category_id->term_id;
    $child_categories = get_term_children( $term_id, $taxonomy );
    for($i=0;$i<count($child_categories);$i++){
            $category_name = get_term( $child_categories[$i], $taxonomy );
            $catreal_name = $category_name->name;
            $catfilterfull = str_replace(' ', '', $catreal_name);
            echo '<a href="#'.$catfilterfull.'" title="'.$catfilter.'">'.$catreal_name.'</a>';
        }

    ?>






    </div>
<div class="gallery-viewer">
<div id="portfolio-wrapper">
<div id="portfolio-list" class="row">

        <?php while ( $query->have_posts() ) : $query->the_post(); ?>
        <div id="post-<?php the_ID(); ?>" class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-3 portfolio-item all
        <?php 
            foreach((get_the_category()) as $catname) {  
            if ($catname->category_parent != '') {  
                $catfilter = ( $catname->cat_name != 'local' ) ? $catname->cat_name . '' : '';
                $catfilterfull = str_replace(' ', '', $catfilter);
                echo ' '.$catfilterfull;
            } }

             ?>
        ">
            <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" class="thumbnail">
            <?php the_post_thumbnail( array(250, 250) ); ?>
            <div class="caption"><?php the_title(); ?></div></a>

        </div>
        <?php endwhile;
        wp_reset_postdata(); ?>
         </div>
        <div class="clearboth"></div>
         </div>
    </div>
    </div>
<?php $myvariable = ob_get_clean();
return $myvariable;
}
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you add a new custom post type, you need to flush your permalinks.

Go to Settings -> Permalinks in the admin and hit save.

Comment: wow such a simple answer to a problem that took me 2 days. thanks friend. i will make it as an answer in 11 minutes (when the site allows)